# django how to disable & enable email verification in admin panel

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project and i want to be able to disable or enable email registration verification in admin panel, with a radio button, if it's set to ON, when user registers to site need to verify email, but if it's set to OFF user account activate after registration and don't need to activate account with email verification

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are having a good time.

I would like the purpose behind allowing email verification after registration because it's sole purpose is to validate authentic users and not allow unidentified login attempt to pass.

Because there have been so many hacking attempts just because of insecure security steps on login panel itself these days, I think it is better if we retain the email verification and not switch its permission.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm thinking about it i find out you are right

Comment: My pleasure @Captain.Andreas.